# ANTRL4: TestRig error

Tags: antlr, dsl, antlrworks

I am just trying to get ANTLR to run following those instructions: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4

The grammar is translated into code, but when I want to call TestRig, I'm getting the error "Can't load Hello as lexer or parser".

TestRig is located in file C:\bin\grun.cmd and contains this command

> java -cp .;C:\LIBS\Java\ANTLR\antlr-4.1-complete.jar
> org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig %1 %2

Is anything wrong with that?

When I try to start TestRig from the ANTLWorks IDE I'm receiving warnings like:

> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation
> processor
> 'org.netbeans.modules.openide.modules.PatchedPublicProcessor' less
> than -source '1.7'
>
> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from
> annotation processor
> 'org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.ServiceProviderProcessor' less than
> -source '1.7'
>
> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor
> 'org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NamedServiceProcessor' less than
> -source '1.7'
>
> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor
> 'org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbBundleProcessor' less than
> -source '1.7'

and errors like:

> line 1:7 token recognition error at: ' '
>
> ...........
>
> line 1:0 missing 'hello' at 'grammar'

On Linux I'm experiencing another problem with ANTLRWorks2:
For whatever reason the menu bar doesn't work so that it's impossible to select anything from there. Anyway, clicking on an icon below the menu bar works.

What might be wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year late on this but in case others have the issue...

I am guessing you named your grammar file 'hello' instead of 'Hello' or you didn't copy the contents correctly.
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4

The warnings about 'RELEASE_6' are supposedly harmless according to this bug report.
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210286
I am still getting these warnings in ANTLRWorks2.1. According to the final post it may be fixed in the NetBeans plugin. However, as far as I can tell this plugin has been recently broken.

I can't help you with IDE issues on Linux.